# Stop using an app during work hours

Tags: applications, installation

I need to avoid using a personal messaging application in my android phone during work time. 
One way is to uninstall the app before work starts, and install again after the work time. 
Or use some app blockers ? 
Or... what else ?

Comment: Disable app, configuration and personal data won't be gone either.

Comment: @IrfanLatif Great idea. But I'm lazy :-) to disable and enable on daily basis. Is there any apps available to auto disable and auto enable ?

Comment: Automation apps can possibly do but I prefer commandline solutions. I'd run a cron job if I need to. Btw disabling takes hardly 10 seconds. From some launchers e.g. Nova, app's settings can be directly accessed by long pressing app icon.

Comment: @IrfanLatif I'm a programmer, but I'm not that much in to android programming. What I need is, I need to feel I like I don't have WhatsApp messenger during work hours. Right now, I'm using App Block to allow me to use WhatsApp only for 15 minutes and I select "strict" mode, which do the job well.

Comment: Do you have root access?

Comment: @ReddyLutonadio No

Comment: You can use "Automate" app to disable the notifications for your messaging app (see question https://android.stackexchange.com/questions/213886/how-to-prevent-an-apps-notification-from-updating-while-the-screen-is-off). I'm not sure if you can set it to disable/enable the notifications on specific times, but if you can't then you can achieve the same by using Tasker and secure settings plugin. But I just saw that you don't have root, so probably both solutions won't work for you. if you have android pie, the Digital wellbeing function might be able to hide the notifications.

Comment: Or you could just set up the "do not disturb" mode to meet your requirements.

Comment: @mnd Actually, I am not only need to stop notification but the complete app.

Comment: then I guess getting root would be your only option if you want to automate the stopping/killing of the app.

Answer (score 0):

Depends on your Android version. But go to Settings -->Apps--> Choose App-->Notifications-->And then chose option like Calls, Messages and so on.
I think that this is better than app blocker, becaose most app blockers will completly block apps and messages and this methond will only give you no notification and it takes 15 seconds.